# Loop over dictionary

Tags: javascript

Js newbie here.
I have two variables, the value of which I'm extracting from user input (which is a string).

Now I have a dictionary :

```
let dict = {
          'p':  "100 units" ,
          'q': "200  units",
          'g': "500  units",
          'e': "10  units"
        }
```

What I want to do here is to write a condition that allows users to enter only the key values in the dict (for example, **"p for 100 units"**), that is, sends a fallback response "This option is not available"(console.log)
If I do this using a loop on Object.keys(dict), the response gets sent 4 times (equal to the number of key-value pairs in the dictionary).

How do I check that what the user has entered corresponds to my dictionary and send a response only once if he hasn't? I reckon I would have to loop over the dictionary in any case.

I also want to place a return for the if block. i.e:

```
if(whatever){
//code

return 0
}
else return 1
```

Any other ideas/approaches I can try?

Comment: You don't need to loop. It's a dictionary. Just lookup the letter, and see if it exists: `if (dict.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {...}`

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, If user enters 'p', you want to console '100 units'? If user enters a letter which isn't in the object(dict), you want to console, "This option is not available", right? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: @Siddharth yes exactly

Comment: @Siddharth can you please suggest an edit (or tell me where) if it's confusing? I tried to be clear.

Comment: @blex has already answered your question, you don't need to write any loop, just check that condition, if you want to read more about `hasOwnProperty`, visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.keys returns an array of keys like so:

```
let dict = {
          'p':  "100 units" ,
          'q': "200  units",
          'g': "500  units",
          'e': "10  units"}
          
  const keys = Object.keys(dict)
  console.log(keys) // output ['p', 'q', 'g', 'e']
```

Therefore if you want to check the letter a user enters you need to loop through the array of keys and use if statement inside the loop to check the user input:

```
let userInput = 'g'

for(key of keys){
  if(key === userInput){
    console.log(dict[key]) //output 500 units
  }else{
    console.log('Fall back response')
  }
}
```

Read the documentation here for details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `in` operator to check if a key is present in an object, like:

```
if(input in dict){}
```

Using it, you can simply create a such program, where `dict` is your object and `input` is the key the user pressed:

```
console.log(input in dict ? 'Chosen' + dict[input] : 'Fallback text')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code you might find useful:

```
letter="e";
console.log((units=dict[letter])?letter+" for "+units:"This option is not available");
```

`letter` is the user's input.  You could/should check for no input|more than one letter.
`dict[letter]` returns value for key `letter`.  If not found, it returns undefined which is like false.
We assign that value to a variable `units` so we don't have to look it up again (useful in very complicated objects and functions to save resources).
The `condition?ifTrue:ifFalse` is evaluated (I've put the condition in parentheses - to avoid having to think what might be evaluated without them.  Probably the same.  Usually, I used this format: `((condition)?(do/value if true):(do/value if false))`.
The rest should be obvious.

I would recommend consistent indentation and spacing:

```
let dict = {
  'p': "100 units",
  'q': "200 units",
  'g': "500 units",
  'e':  "10 units"
};
const keys = Object.keys(dict);
console.log(keys) // output ['p', 'q', 'g', 'e']
```